# I have a lot of select the same classes, how to change the color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a lot of select the same classes, how to change the color of select?

If selected option = first then the `background-color` of select should be `red`, if selected option = second then `green`.

```
<select class="select">
   <option value="first" selected>first</option>
   <option value="second">second</option>
</select>

<select class="select">
   <option value="first">first</option>
   <option value="second" selected>second</option>
</select>
```

Comment: _how to change the color_ color of what ?

Comment: well. What have you tried to achieve this ? share some code

Comment: You are expected to have a crack at this yourself at least. Did you do any research?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a lot of select the same classes

You could attach a change event using this common class then use the `this` keyword to know which select is changed, like :

```js
$('.select').on('change', function() {
  var selected_value = $(this).val();
  var color = "";

  if (selected_value === 'first') {
    color = 'red';
  } else if (selected_value === 'second') {
    color = 'green';
  }

  $(this).css('background-color', color);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="first">first</option>
  <option value="second">second</option>
</select>

<select class="select">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="first">first</option>
  <option value="second">second</option>
</select>
```